# how to print a report in shiny using r markdown?

Tags: r, function, shiny, report, r-markdown

I need to print a report from a shiny application using r markdown. I have been trying to follow the examples, but after many hours, I need some help.

There are 4 files:  app.R, report.Rmd, calculations.R and [datos.xlsx](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nx1npytqjrq1etb/datos.xlsx?dl=0)
datos.xlsx is an excel file with information to be used by a function defined in calculations.R and used by app.R

app.R is expected to provide the result on the screen and a downloadable report.  I do not get the latter and I have been strugling the last two days with this.

Thank you very much!

app.R:

```
ui <- fluidPage(

    titlePanel("Calculations"),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        fileInput("file1","Select excel file with data", accept=c("excel",".xlsx",".xls")),

        "When are available on the screen, you can download the report",
        radioButtons('format', 'Document format', c('PDF', 'HTML', 'Word'),
                     inline = TRUE),
        downloadButton('downloadReport')
        ),

    mainPanel(
      tableOutput(outputId = "tabla")
      )
    ))


server <- function(input, output) {

  source("./calculations.R")

  output$tabla<-renderTable({
    infile<-input$file1
    if(is.null(infile))return(NULL)
    calculo(infile$datapath)})


  output$downloadReport <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste('my-report', sep = '.', switch(
        input$format, PDF = 'pdf', HTML = 'html', Word = 'docx'
      ))
    },

    content = function(file) {
      src <- normalizePath('report.Rmd')

      # temporarily switch to the temp dir, in case you do not have write
      # permission to the current working directory
      owd <- setwd(tempdir())
      on.exit(setwd(owd))
      file.copy(src, 'report.Rmd', overwrite = TRUE)

      library(rmarkdown)
      out <- render('report.Rmd', switch(
        input$format,
        PDF = pdf_document(), HTML = html_document(), Word = word_document()
      ))
      file.rename(out, file)
    }
  )

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

report.Rmd:

---

title: "Dynamic report"
output: word_document

---

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE,warning=FALSE,message = FALSE)
```

Results

```
print(output$tabla)
```

calculations.R

```
library(xlsx)
calculo<-function(archivo){
  incrementos_descuentos<-read.xlsx(archivo,sheetName="incrementos - descuentos",  check.names = FALSE)  
  incrementos_descuentos$`Desde / mm`<-as.numeric(as.character(incrementos_descuentos$`Desde / mm`))
  incrementos_descuentos$`A  / mm`<-as.numeric(as.character(incrementos_descuentos$`A  / mm`))
  incrementos_descuentos$`Volumen / L`<-as.numeric(as.character(incrementos_descuentos$`Volumen / L`))
  incrementos_descuentos$`Resultado L/m`<-as.numeric(as.character(incrementos_descuentos$`Resultado L/m`))
  incrementos_descuentos$`Resultado L/m`<-incrementos_descuentos$`Volumen / L`/(incrementos_descuentos$`A  / mm`-incrementos_descuentos$`Desde / mm`)
Resutado<-incrementos_descuentos
Resutado
}
```

Comment: Downloading files may be problematic in Rstudio. Have you tried running from a browser?

Comment: Hi!, I uploaded the app to  www.shinyapps.io in order to use a browser, but is the same.  I wonder that the script in the .Rmd file is wrong at least.

Comment: Do you get any error(s) on the R console or in the app?

Comment: On the console.

Comment: You Rmd chunks appear to be missing the backticks `(```{r} code ```)`, unless something went wrong when pasting here.

Comment: Yes, I had problems when pasting the Rmd chuncks.  I had to remove backticks.

Comment: This is the message: "Quitting from lines 12-13 (report.Rmd) 

Warning: Error in $.shinyoutput: Reading objects from shinyoutput object not allowed.
  [No stack trace available]"

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I found the solution, after many days.

I added in app.R a reactive object:

```
informe <- reactive({
    infile<-input$file1
    if(is.null(infile))return(NULL)
    calculo(infile$datapath)
  })
```

and the I called it from report.Rmd as informe()